# Fontsize of Headlines on pages with landscape with different fontsize

Tags: header-footer, fontsize, koma-script, landscape

I use scrreprt and want to show a longtable (more exactly ltxtable) in landscape-mode on two pages. Fontsize concerning every letter of that table shown in landscape-mode shall be 8pt. Before the table and on the following pages I will continue with fontsize 12pt. On the first page with my ltxtable Headline and Footline have 8pt and on the second page both have 12pt, which I already wanted on the first page to happen.
I use TeX Live 2015/Debian as well as MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit and compile with PDLLaTeX (pdfTeX, Version 3)

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontotocandhead, 12pt, DIV=calc,%
headsepline, headexclude=false, footsepline,%
footexclude=false, footheight=25pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{dejavu}

\usepackage[automark,plainfootsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}
\ifoot*{\strut XXXarbeit an der\\XXX Universität YYY\strut}
\cfoot*{\strut\\\pagemark\strut}
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}--~\thepage~--\strut}}

\recalctypearea

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\Blindtext[3]

\addchap[tocentry={}]{Appendix}
\addsec[tocentry={}]{Tables}

\begin{landscape}
\LTXtable{\linewidth}{tables/table-test.auto}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

File table-test.auto loks like this:

```
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=8pt}

\begin{longtable}{p{15mm}p{35mm}Xp{40mm}p{15mm}}

\caption{Main characteristics of the included studies} \\
\toprule
Study & Population & Intervention & Results & Category \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{Main characteristics of the included studies - continued} \\
\toprule
Study & Population & Intervention & Results & Category \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
Study & Population & Intervention & Results & Category \\
\bottomrule
\endfoot
\midrule
Study & Population & Intervention & Results & Category \\
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\label{tab:tabelle02}

Text & Text & Text & Text & Text \\
Text & Text & Text & Text & Text \\

\end{longtable}
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=12pt}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I am getting an error even if I comment out the `\KOMAoptions{fontsize=}` lines, possibly there's an error with your table construction.

Comment: Sorry, but if I delete the \KOMAoptions{fontsize=} lines, I don't get an error. Then all Headers and Footers are 12pt, but the table looks ugly with so much information in 12pt and takes a lot of pages. I assume I don't use \KOMAoptions the right way, maybe there is something missing. KOMA is new to me.

Comment: Can't you just say `{\small\begin{longtable}...\end{longtable}\par}` or specify the font size explicitly if none of the off-the-peg sizes are suitable? E.g. `\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont` or whatever.

Comment: @cfr: You helped me a lot, I'd stuck to KOMA where it was not necessary. Thank you, I can continue my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the value of KOMA-option `fontsize` inside the document, the normal font size `\normalsize` and all depending sizes like `\small`, `\footnotesize` etc. will be recalculated. Your changes of `fontsize` are local, i.e. they are reset at the end of the `landscape` environment automatically. But when the first page of your table is shipped out the change of `\normalsize` and `\footnotesize` is active and therefore header and footer of this page are affected.

If only the font of the table should be smaller, I would suggest to use a depending font size. With your document font size of 12pt, the font size used by \scriptsize is 8pt.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mytest.auto}
\scriptsize
\begin{longtable}{p{15mm}p{35mm}Xp{40mm}p{15mm}}
\caption{Main characteristics of the included studies} \\
\toprule
Study & Population & Intervention & Results & Category \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{Main characteristics of the included studies - continued} \\
\toprule
Study & Population & Intervention & Results & Category \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
Study & Population & Intervention & Results & Category \\
\bottomrule
\endfoot
\midrule
Study & Population & Intervention & Results & Category \\
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\label{tab:tabelle02}
Text & Text & Text & \blindtext & Text \\
Text & Text & Text & Text & Text \\
Text & Text & Text & \blindtext & Text \\
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[
    headings=optiontotocandhead,
    12pt,
    DIV=calc,
    headsepline,
    headinclude,
    footsepline,
    footinclude,
    footheight=25pt
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{dejavu}
\usepackage[automark,plainfootsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}
\ifoot*{\strut XXXarbeit an der\\XXX Universität YYY\strut}
\cfoot*{\strut\\\pagemark\strut}
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}--~\thepage~--\strut}}
\recalctypearea
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext[3]
\addchap[tocentry={}]{Appendix}
\addsec[tocentry={}]{Tables}
\begin{landscape}
\LTXtable{\linewidth}{mytest.auto}
\end{landscape}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Alternativaly you can set the font size to a fixed value using something like `\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont`. Note that command `\fontsize` does not change the sizes used by `\normalsize`, `\small` etc.